# Loop through multiple variables jQuery for display to user

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do here is loop through `donation` and `donation_cause` variables which come from multiple checked radio buttons. Then I display them to the user within `ul#selected-amounts`.

What I'd like the code to do is display, for example:

```
<ul id="selected-amounts">
   <li>$FOO lorem ipsum BAR</li>
   <li>$FOO2 lorem ipsum BAR2</li>
</ul>
```

What it's doing right now:

```
<ul id="selected-amounts">
   <li>$FOO,FOO2 lorem ipsum BAR</li>
   <li>$BAR2</li>
</ul>
```

I'm still learning jQuery, and I don't understand why `donation` is displaying as a comma separated array and `donation_cause` is displaying the way I want it to. I feel like this might be a place to use `.each()` but I haven't managed to figure it out.

The current applicable code appears below:

```
amount_chosen.change(function(){ //when the dollar amount changes

    var donation = [];
    var donation_cause = [];

    $.each($('input.dollar-value:checked'), function(){
        donation.push($(this).val());
        donation_cause.push($(this).attr('name'));
    });

    $("#selected-amounts").html("<li>&#36;"+donation+" to "+donation_cause.join("</li><li>&#36;")).css("display", "block");

});
```

Thank you!

Comment: small hint: when you do `"+donation+"`, `donation` is an array. In JS when an array is concatenated to a string, the function `toString` is called, which results in a string with all elements in the array coma separated. (this is not jQuery specific)

Comment: You don't need the arrays in the first place; just use `$("#selected-amounts").append("<li>$" + $(this).val() + " to " + $(this).attr('name') + "</li>");` in your each loop instead.

Comment: @Kaddath Thank you! I had a suspicion that was the case, but I wasn't sure why it was happening. Knowing that `toString` is called here makes sense and helps me understand what I did wrong.

Comment: @ChrisG That's a great solution and cuts down on code length. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting an array in a string: `"..." + donation + "..."` implicitly converts it to a string, which is the same as calling `.join(",")` on it.

You need a loop.

---

This is best done in the loop you have already instead of creating extra arrays.

You can make use of jQuery features to escape any special characters and make the code less error prone while you are at it

```
$("#selected-amounts").empty(); // Erase existing content

$.each($('input.dollar-value:checked'), function(){
    const donation = $(this).val();
    const cause = $(this).attr('name');
    $("#selected-amounts").append(
        $("<li />").text("$" + donation + " to " + cause);
    );
});

$("#selected-amounts").css("display", "block");
```

Comment: Thank you, @Quentin! What is the reasoning behind using `const` here for the variables rather than `push` to create the arrays? Is it because `push` simply updates the array when looping through the checked inputs whereas `const` only grabs the single value for each loop through a checked input (thereby grabbing single values and not creating arrays)?

Comment: There's no point in looping over the data twice (once to put it into arrays and ones to do something with the arrays), and splitting the data between two arrays just makes it messy to put together. You can skip over the `const` assignments and just use the expressions directly in the string, it is split out to keep things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

There are problems on this code.

```
$("#selected-amounts").html("<li>&#36;"+donation+" to "+donation_cause.join("</li><li>&#36;")).css("display", "block");
```

Currently, `donation` and `donation_cause` is array value so `"<li>&#36;"+donation` has the same meaning of `"<li>&#36;"+donation.toString()`.

To add `<li>` tag for each item of `donation` array, it is needed to loop the items and add one by one as follows.

```
let htmlCode = "";
for (let i = 0; i < donation.length; i ++) {
  htmlCode += "<li>&#36;" + donation[i] + " to " + donation_cause[i] + "</li>";
}
$("#selected-amounts").html(htmlCode).css("display", "block");
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, @Derek.W. It's helpful! I ultimately went with a shorter solution, but I appreciate seeing this.